# GregorianCalendar returns wrong DAY_OF_WEEK in Java

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek, gregorian-calendar, weekday

This code:

```
Calendar calendar;
calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day);
week_day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

returns wrong value.

For example

> - year=**2013**, month=**3**, day=**31**

returns the same value of

> - year=**2013**, month=**4**, day=**1**.

How I can do this correctly ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `Java`, months start from `0`.

`Month 3 day 31` is `April 31`, that does not exist, then it will be shifted to `May` 1,

`Month 4 day 1` is `May 1`, the same day as above.